# How to convert a LateX code to Image using a vector template

Tags: algorithms, svg, illustrator

I want to use illustrator to create a fancier look for my algorithm boxes. Is there any way that I can set a script (or any other way really) to take the algorithmic text on latex and convert it to the template I made in illustrator (could be SVG)?

If not, what methods are out there what are you guys using for a purpose like this?

**Edit:** Here is what I have i.e. let's say the code is

```latex
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Regret-Matching}\label{regret_matching}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{Regret-Matching}{N}
        \State Cumulative regrets for players $R_i \leftarrow 0$ 
        \State $S[a] \leftarrow 0$ for $\forall a \in \mathcal{A}$
        \ForAll{$t \in {1, 2, 3, ..., T}$}
            \State initialize $\sigma$
            \State $\sigma[a] \leftarrow \max(R_i[a], 0)$ for $\forall a \in \mathcal{A}$
            \State $\Theta \leftarrow \sum_{a\in \mathcal{A}}{\sigma[a]}$
            \ForAll{$a \in \mathcal{A}$}
                \If {$\Theta > 0$}
                    \State $\sigma[a] \leftarrow \sigma[a]/\Theta$
                \Else
                    \State $\sigma[a] \leftarrow 1/|\mathcal{A}|$
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
            \State $S[a] \leftarrow S[a] + \sigma[a]$
            \State Get action $a \in \mathcal{A}$ according to strategy profile $\sigma$
            \State $R_i[a^{'}] \leftarrow R_i[a^{'}] + u(a^{'}) - u(a)$ for $\forall a^{'} \in \mathcal{A}$
            \State $\Theta \leftarrow \sum_{a\in \mathcal{A}}{S[a]}$
            \ForAll{$a \in \mathcal{A}$}
                \If {$\Theta > 0$}
                    \State $\sigma_\text{avg}[a] \leftarrow S[a] / \Theta$
                \Else
                    \State $\sigma_\text{avg}[a] \leftarrow 1/|\mathcal{A}|$
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
        \EndFor
    \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

The visual result will be;

[image: latex look]

and I want to convert it to something like this;

[image: Vector]

Currently, I am doing it by hand and it's taking time. I am looking if there is any way to do this smarter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I'm having a bit of trouble following what you mean.  Could you post an example of your algorithm boxes?  Is your question essentially, "how can I take the tex code that made my box and get svg (or something else for Illustrator) instead?"

Comment: @Teepeemm I added what I meant. Essentially it could be any latex piece that somehow needs change, and an SVG and/or any other method to use to change the visual aspects.

Comment: please post a complete document not a fragment. You could use dvisvgm to conver the latex output to svg, but you could more easily just typeset the desired final form in latex using tcolorbox